# nightwatchjs saveScreenshot giving TypeError: The "data" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, TypedArray, or DataView

Tags: nightwatch.js, nightwatch

I am working on an automation prototype using Nightwatch js and when I am trying to save screenshot, it is giving below error

> Error while running .getScreenshot() protocol action: An unknown
> server-side error occurred while processing the command. – An unknown
> server-side error occurred while proces...
>
> ---
>
> TEST FAILURE: 1 error during execution; 0 tests failed, 0 passed
> (10.032s)
>
> TypeError: The "data" argument must be of type string or an instance
> of Buffer, TypedArray, or DataView. Received an instance of Object
> at Object.writeFile (fs.js:1487:5)
> at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:180:23)
>
> FAILED: 1 errors and  1 passed (9.662s)

relevant data for nightwatch.config.js:

```
 test_settings: {
        "screenshots": {
            "enabled": true, // if you want to keep screenshots
            "path": './screenshots' // save screenshots here
          },
```

test file data:

```
.pause(3000).saveScreenshot('./screnshots/test.png');
```

Nightwatch version: "1.5.1"

please note that due to office policy cannot paste complete testcase data here.

[image]

Comment: are you trying to manually take the screenshot or you want nightwatch to take screenshot on failures ?

Comment: @AlapanDas I want to take screenshots on different steps through nighwatch

Comment: Very difficult to debug with just one line, but the command looks correct. I have written a blog on this, may be it can help - https://testersdock.com/nightwatch-js-screenshots/